# "In my workouts", "on my workouts", or "during my workouts"?

Tags: prepositions

Tell me please which one of the following sentence sounds the most natural:

> I generally squat more than I deadlift **in** my workouts.
>
> I generally squat more than I deadlift **on** my workouts.
>
> I generally squat more than I deadlift **during** my workouts.

Comment: "In" and "during" both sound natural to me. "On" does not and is definitely wrong.

Answer (score -1):

**During** would be the most correct word to use in this context although the word **in** would be used colloquially and therefore is acceptable. **On** is incorrect.

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: I think the downvote is because you don't back up your answer with any particular reasons. Why is "during" more correct than "in"? Why is "on" incorrect? I agree with your answer, but good answers support their claims